# 上の+number - how should we translate it?

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning

How should be translated the phrase "上の二" in the next sentence? :

> 日本の[食堂]{しょくどう}に行くと、同じ料理が[並]{なみ}と上の二[種類]{しゅるい}あることがある。

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should parse that sentence as "『同じ料理が、「並{なみ}」と「上{じょう}」の「[2]{に}種類{しゅるい}」ある』ことがある". 並 is ordinary grade, 上 is high grade, 2種類 is two kinds.